# AngularJS text box and the Calendar icon needs to appear side by side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the the input button and the calendar icon appear side by side but currently it shows like below

[image]

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label style="font-size: medium">From Date (yyyy-mm-dd)</label>
    <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"
            id="fromDate"
            name="fromDate"
            uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
            ng-model="request.fromDate"
            is-open="popup1.opened"
            datepicker-options="dateOptions"
            ng-required="true"
            close-text="Close"
            alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"
            required />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </p>
    <div style="color:maroon" ng-messages="homeForm.fromDate.$error"
        ng-if="homeForm.fromDate.$touched">
        <div ng-message="required">This field is required</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Earlier I had a separate `span` class for the calendar button and it made it even worse:

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

[image]

I tried to use `<div class="col-md-6">` on both fields and it makes the both the fields appear side by side  like

[image]

Comment: can you share a plunkr

Comment: Try applying `width:auto` to the input